# Angular 6+: Atualização da página vai para a área de Login da aplicação

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end

Eu realizei a composição do meu CanActivate e o CanLoad, através da classe LoggedInGuard. O problema é que sempre que atualizo a página, sou redirecionado para a página de Login, mesmo logado. Abaixo a minha classe **LoggedInGuard**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanLoad, CanActivate {
  constructor(private signinService: SigninService, private router: Router) { }

  checkAuthentication(path: string): boolean {
    const loggedin = this.signinService.isLoggedin();
    if (!loggedin) {
      this.router.navigate([ this.signinService.handleLogin(`/${ path }`) ]);
    }
    return loggedin;
  }

  canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
    return this.checkAuthentication(route.path);
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.checkAuthentication(route.routeConfig.path);
  }

}
```

Meu SignService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SigninService {

  private baseUrl: string;
  private user: User;
  private lastUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.baseUrl = `${environment.url}/auth/signin`;
    this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe((e: NavigationEnd) => this.lastUrl = e.url);
  }

  public isLoggedin(): boolean {
    return this.user !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('token') !== undefined;
  }

  public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', username)
      .set('password', password);
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.baseUrl}`, params).do((user: User) => this.user = user);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.user = undefined;
    this.handleLogin('/');
  }

  public handleLogin(path: string = this.lastUrl) {
    this.router.navigate(['/signin', btoa(path)]);
  }

  public get UserDetail(): User {
    return this.user;
  }


}
```

Os Serviços estão setados dentro dos providers de responsabilidade. Em meu, **SigninComponent** eo realizo o Login da seguinte forma:

```
public login(): void {
    console.log(this.signinForm);
    this.signinService.login(this.signinForm.value.username, this.signinForm.value.password ).subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.user = user;
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.user.token.token);
      this.isSuccess = true;
      this.message = 'Usuário encontrado. Aguarde um momento!';
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.isSuccess = false;
        this.message = err.error.error.message;
      console.error(err);
      }, () => {
        this.router.navigate([ atob(this.navigateTo) ]);
    });
  }
```

Comment: o metodo isLoggedin ta retornando true ou false??

Comment: Fala @EduardoVargas! Então... Parece que ele perde a referência de usuário quando atualiza a página. Algo que eu não gostaria que acontecesse. então, o método para a ser falso! Eu fiz somente o localstorage, mas não acho muito confiante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução 1:
Como o User não se trata de uma Interface, a referência é perdida. Então, troquei o formato de Interface para Classe, e instanciei o mesmo.

```
this.user = new User();
```

Da forma acima, não consegui perder a minha referência.

A outra forma, é trabalhando com localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', this.user.token.token);
```

É de prache, ao usar o set com um tooken exclusivo, então, setar token, que é uma palavra tão comum dentro das aplicações pode gerar conflitos caso tenha outras aplicações que use o mesmo termo. É raro, mas já via casos acontecerem. Então, aprevie como **thiago_token**, por exemplo.

Sempre quando atualizar, o sistema vai verificar se o token esta no localstorage ou sessionstorage. Onde você preferir gravar!